# Does Google Docs online use HTML5?

Tags: google-drive, html5

Does Google Docs online use HTML5 technology or use Gears now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the HTML source, the doctype declaration at docs.google.com is `<!DOCTYPE html>` which [indicates it is HTML 5](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp).

Answer (score 3):

Google started [phasing out](http://gearsblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hello-html5.html) Gears.
As of May 2010 Google started [phasing out](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176376) support for offline access in Google Docs through Gears. However, they are still supporting it in order not to break anything.

> The Google spokesman wrote to clarify in a follow-up e-mail, "We're continuing to support Gears so that nothing breaks for sites that use it. But we expect developers to use HTML5 for these features moving forward as it's a standards-based approach that will be available across all browsers."

Source: http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/technology/2009/11/google-gears.html

Also, Google Gears API is deprecated: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/gears/